# Why am I getting missing col specification?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
jeevandsz#COMPUTE_WH@SAMPLE_DB.PUBLIC>SELECT * FROM Q;
+----+----+
|  A |  B |
|----+----|
| 10 | 20 |
+----+----+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.281s
jeevandsz#COMPUTE_WH@SAMPLE_DB.PUBLIC>create materialized view mv as
                                          select
                                              A + 100
                                            from Q;
002022 (42601): SQL compilation error:
Missing column specification
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The computed expression `A + 100` does not have a name, so Snowflake cannot assign one for the MV column. Alias it, and it will work:

```
create materialized view mv as
select
A + 100 as MY_COLUMN_NAME
from Q;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Missing column specification

It means that all expressions in the SELECT list should be named. It could be done by using alias  or by providing optional `(<column_list>)`.

[CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-materialized-view.html):

> ```
> CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] [ SECURE ] MATERIALIZED VIEW [ IF NOT EXISTS ] <name>
> [ COPY GRANTS ]
> ( <column_list> )
> AS <select_statement>
> ```
>
> column_list:
>
> If you do not want the column names in the view to be the same as the column names of the underlying table, you may include a column list in which you specify the column names

[CREATE VIEW:](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-view.html#optional-parameters)

> column_list
>
> **If any of the columns in the view are based on expressions (not just simple column names), then you must supply a column name for each column in the view**

---

Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE Q AS SELECT 10 AS A, 20 AS B;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv(col_name)
AS
SELECT A + 100
FROM Q;

SELECT * FROM mv;
-- COL_NAME
-- 110
```